# PySide get QObject's parent anywhere in its hierarchy

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

Consider I have a class with this kind of structure (`CustomClass` may/may not be on top of the hierarchy):

```
CustomClass

.. QTabWidget

.... QWidget

...... QTreeView
```

In `QTreeView` I have a function that is trying to refer back to `CustomClass`. Right now in order to do this I need to do: `self.parent().parent().parent()`.

Although this works it just feels very sloppy, and if I ever need to change the structure this will fail. Is there some other way to get `CustomClass`? Usually I would pass an instance of it during its constructor which I can call directly, but wondering what's the best practice to go about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feels like a decent procedural way to get it:

```
customClassInst = self.parent()
while customClassInst is not None and type(customClassInst) != CustomClass:
    customClassInst = customClassInst.parent()
```

Any other answers are still welcome :)

Comment: If you want to find the parent `CustomClass` then this is kinda how to do it (though you should probably use `isinstance()` rather than `type() ==`).  But the question title makes it sound like you want the top level widget whether or not it is a `CustomClass` to which the answer is `window()`.

Comment: Thank you, in this case `window()` is exactly what I need. :)

Comment: Not sure if I should make this an answer?  Think I will just to keep things clean ...

Answer (score 1):

The question title leads to a very direct answer.  The `window()` method on `QWidget` returns the ancestor widget that has (or could have) a window-system frame: typically the "top-level" widget that you want to find.  The docs give changing the window title as a canonical use case:

```
self.window().setWindowTitle(newTitle)
```

It returns `self` if the `Qwidget` is a window itself.

However, the text of your question and your own answer give an alternative interpretation: you might alternatively want to find the ancestor that is of a particular type even if it is not the top level widget.  In this case, iterating up through the ancestors is typically the right solution, pretty much as you have written for yourself.  So that would be something like:

```
customClassInst = self.parent()
while customClassInst is not None and not isinstance(customClassInst,CustomClass):
    customClassInst = customClassInst.parent()
```

Note that you should usually use `isinstance` rather than `type() ==` because the former correctly handles sub-classes.

Also note that this code will return `None` if no `CustomClass` is found which may or may not be what you want ...

Comment: Interesting thing to note: I was calling `window()` and it was working very well. Then I started to use `QDockWidget` and noticed when the dock is floating vs docked, `window()` will return different results.

Comment: Yeah good point.  It gives you the "window" which is the guy at the top with the frame, not the logical "top" of the hierarchy.

Comment: It's too bad since it felt like a very clean solution. Still a good answer though if you're not using `QDockWidget`